# How to change loading animation (Spinner) to a set of images?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I want to change the loading (Spinner) animation when the website is loading something.

I don't know if it currently is CSS animation, a set of images, or anything else.

I want to replace that with a set of images that I have as I am going to make it a module.

The question is how to do just that?

Answer (score 0):

Add template in static folder

```
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
<t t-name="Throbber">
```

Then add in manifest qweb [template.xml]